# Linux packet forwarding performance

Tags: linux, performance, ip, forwarding

I’m experiencing performance issues with Linux packet forwarding. I use an old laptop as a router, with `iptables` to handle masquerading and ipv4 forwarding turned on.

- Intranet network is connected to the gigabit built-in NIC
- Internet network cis onnected to a 32bit PCMCIA card

Measured speeds :

- Internet <-> Router : 11.2 MB/s
- Intranet <-> Router : 112 MB/s
- Intranet <-> Internet : no more than 100 KB/s

I can have both interfaces downloading / uploading at the same time without any issue.

Router hardware configuration :

- Pentium M 1.6GHz
- 1.2 GB RAM
- DELL Latitude D410

Software configuration :

- Linux 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 21:36:00 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux (Debian 6)
- `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` set to 1

I have no clue why this is happening, does anyone have an idea of where this performance drop could come from ?

I will try reinstalling the operating system, but I do not think it will change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I already faced a Linux router which wouldn't forward more than about 100kB/s for each connection.

The issue was the Ethernet interface to the ISP equipment was set to half duplex. Fixed by disabling auto-negotiation and manually forcing full duplex. This could be done via ethtool:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Answer (score 0):

> Internet <-> Router : 11.2 MB/s

How was this measured? 100MBit/s Internet pipes are uncommon. Do you have glass fiber at your home? If you have some sort of ADSL, the 100KB/s sound reasonable.

Comment: I'm in a French engineering school which is connected to Internet through [RENATER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renater). The actual internet link is around 1Gb/s, but we're limited by 100Mb switches.

Comment: The we need some more info like distribution, kernel version etc. Try to disable "power management" in the BIOS - maybe your CPU just sleeps longer ;-)

Comment: If you have a **shared** 1GB pipe at you school, how do you know it is *free*? It might just be saturated to the point where you only can get 100KB/s. This was always the case when I went to my university...

Comment: Have you tried testing the bandwidth between the internet and your router? You could ssh in and use wget or curl to download something large to the router.

Comment: JasonWoof: That's exactly what I did. Turbo J: We're not that many students living on-site, and it's the week-end. When I manually forward a port, using netcat, it works like a charm. I'll reinstall the router tonight and get back to you when it's done.

Comment: Just did a fresh install ; the problem remains.

Comment: As most of us have no crystal ball, more info might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had done it. Edited question to include kernel version + what I changed. I tried with another computer and exactly the same software, it works as it should. I'm going to test with fragrouter to see if that's purely a kernel problem.

Comment: I'm getting more and more puzzled as I test things : routing schema is _Local1 <-Router1-> Local2 <-Router2-> Local3 <-Router3-> Internet_ . The faulty router is Router1 (debian box). _Local1<->Local2_ is OK, _Local1<->Local3_ is OK too, but _Local1<->Internet_ has performance problems while _Router1<->Internet_ is OK . -- Thanks for your help, but I think I'll leave it there and swap the 'Router1' machine.

Comment: Have you checked for packet loss? You can try ping or analyze a trace with Wireshark (new versions colorize such errors). Has the final client bad tuned TCP performance (windows) ?